# Mirror modifier issue

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I'm a new user to Blender

I am aware of most tools and I'm still learning but I'm stuck on placing a mirror. The mirror is directly against the plane and yes I'm aware of the origin.

I want to mirror the axis and not from the origin even if the origin is off the mirror is still getting to that spot. I managed to get it to work on my laptop but even with the same settings I cant get it that way on my main computer. does anyone have a suggestion on what am I doing wrong?

The blue line is the middle of my project

[image: mirrored] [image: original]

Comment: Without seeing an image of your whole screen and more details, it's impossible to know exactly what you're trying to achieve. Add an image of the whole screen via the Window > Save Screenshot menu including the mirror modifier in the side panel. It would also be useful if you could upload your Blend file. - https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Can you show the modifier settings?

Answer (score 1):

A mirror modifier does not care about the 'center of your project'.
A mirror modifier can only use an Object Origin as it's center. Luckily, we can choose to use the Origin of a **different** object for the Mirror Modifier.

Please follow these steps:

- Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to World Origin*
- While in *Object Mode*, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Empty > Plain Axes*.
- Select your object with the *Mirror Modifier*.
- In the *Mirror Modifier*, select the Empty object that you created as the *Mirror Object*:

[image]

Now you can move your object around and the *Mirror Modifier* will work around the Empty object (which is at the 'center of your project').

Comment: Although it is not necessary to use a different object, since you can always move the vertices away from the origin in _Edit Mode_... I'm not sure the OP tried that because the screenshots are all in _Object Mode_.

Comment: Agreed, I was taking an educated guess at what s/he is trying to achieve.